# IPython parallel DirectView.apply does not run in parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, ipython, ipython-parallel

For some reason I cannot get IPython parallel function `DirectView.apply()` to really parallelize a function call. `DirectView.map()` works as expected. Am I doing something wrong here? A working example script

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from ipyparallel import Client, require

@require(time)
def wait(seconds=1):
    time.sleep(seconds)

if __name__=='__main__':
    client = Client()
    print('engine ids: {}'.format(client.ids))
    dview = client.direct_view((0, 1, 2, 3))
    dview.block = False
    print('view targets: {}'.format(dview.targets))

    print('dview.apply...')
    t0 = datetime.now()
    results = [dview.apply(wait) for i in range(4)]
    while len(results) > 0:
        results.pop(0).get()
    print('time: {}'.format(datetime.now() - t0))

    print('dview.map... ')
    t0 = datetime.now()
    results = dview.map(wait, [1]*4)
    print('time: {}'.format(datetime.now() - t0))
```

prints

```
engine ids: [0, 1, 2, 3]
view targets: [0, 1, 2, 3]
dview.apply...
time: 0:00:04.021680
dview.map... 
time: 0:00:01.013941
```

showing that `apply` clearly does not perform as I expected.

My system is Ubuntu 14.04, Python 3.4.3, IPython 4.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I misinterpreted the documentation. [Here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.parallel.client.view.html#IPython.parallel.client.view.View.apply) it says that  *`apply(f, *args, **kwargs)` calls `f(*args, **kwargs)` on remote engines, returning the result.*

If I understand correctly, this means that the function is applied on all of the engines, instead of running it once on just one of them.

Comment: I think it may depend on the kind of view you're using - doing it with a load-balanced view may only run it on one. I'm not sure of that, though.